# Prefuse set different color to every nodes group

Tags: java, data-visualization, prefuse

I am new to prefuse and don't understand several things regarding nodes.

1. How can I get an event raised whenever a node clicked?
2. How can I group similar nodes with the same color?
3. How can I keep an extra meta-data on every node?

Its important to say that I build the graph in real-time and not loading it from any file.

Thanks,
Ozrad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three answers to your three questions:

1. The best way to react on node clicks is to extend `prefuse.controls.ControlAdapter` and add it to the `Display`.
2. `prefuse.action.assignment.DataColorAction` assigns color based on a data field. For more advanced scenarios you can use `ColorAction` with predicates or extend the class `DataColorAction`.
3. You can add columns to the node table to store metadata. A column can also store objects if you need it:

   ```
   vg.getNodeTable().addColumn("meta", MyMetaData.class);
   ```

Comment: Thank you! do you know where can I find references or code examples to these issues?

Comment: some examples are in https://github.com/prefuse/Prefuse/tree/master/demos/prefuse/demos